# What is the directory for a background image in a CSS file?

Tags: jira, confluence, jira-plugin

I am new to Confluence. I am playing decorators and CSS.

This is my atlassian-plugin.xml:

```
<plugin-info>
    <description>${project.description}</description>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <vendor name="${project.organization.name}" url="${project.organization.url}" />
    <param name="plugin-icon">images/ohanaFavicon.png</param>
    <param name="plugin-logo">images/ohanaPluginLogo.gif</param>
</plugin-info>

<resource type="i18n" name="i18n" location="mysite" />

<web-resource key="mysite-resources" name="mysite Web Resources">
    <dependency>com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs</dependency>
    <context>mysite</context>
</web-resource>

<theme key="mysiteheme" name="Mysite Theme" class="com.atlassian.confluence.themes.BasicTheme">
    <description>A theme for tests</description>
    <param name="includeClassicStyles" value="false" />
    <resource type="download" name="default-theme.css" location="/includes/css/default-theme.css">
        <param name="source" value="webContext" />
    </resource>
    <resource type="download" name="mysite.css" location="/theme-mysite/css/mysite.css" />      
    <resource type="download" name="mysite.js" location="/theme-mysite/js/mysite.js" /> 
    <resource type="download" key="images" name="images/" location="/theme-mysite/images"/>
    <layout key="${atlassian.plugin.key}:main" />
</theme>

<layout key="main" name="Main Decorator" overrides="/decorators/main.vmd" class="com.atlassian.confluence.themes.VelocityDecorator">
    <resource type="velocity" name="decorator" location="/theme-mysite/decorators/main.vmd" />
</layout>
```

In mysite.css, I have the following CSS rule:

```
background: url(images/header-bkgd.png) 5px -115px;
```

However, I am not able to see the display of the background image. What is missing in what I did? The "images" directory is under "theme-mysite" directory, which is under the "resources" directory.

A broader question: I have read the book <> and did quite online search. But I am still not able to find any  sample or tutorial explaining how to refer background images in a CSS file. Where to acquire such knowledge?

Best.

**Update**

I tried this:

```
background: url(../images/header-bkgd.png)
```

When looking at the change in Confluence, Chrome shows 404 for the image and the path to it is:

```
http://localhost:1990/confluence/s/en_GB/6441/NOCACHE/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/_/download/resources/images/header-bkgd.png
```

I also tried

```
background: url(../theme-mysite/images/header-bkgd.png);
```

The generated path in Chrome is:

```
http://localhost:1990/confluence/s/en_GB/6441/NOCACHE/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/_/download/resources/theme-mysite/images/header-bkgd.png
```

The image does not exist either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it resolved myself. I need to add this:

```
<resource type="download" key="images" name="images/" location="/theme-mysite/images"/>
```

outside '...'

Answer (score 0):

You try to change like this

```
background: url(../images/header-bkgd.png) 5px -115px;
```

Comment: Hoàng, thanks for chiming in. I tried that and it is not working. See my updates to the post.